# profiling gcloud spark-submit with stackdriver

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, profiling, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to check whether if it is possible to profile my spark-scala application, using google stackdriver profiler, when using gcloud spark-submit.

I have gone through the user guide/manual available on the google cloud docs but it is not clear.
As per their documentation I can profile a JAVA application but there is no mention of how to setup this profiler for spark-scala applications on gcloud.

Would you happen to know anything about this? - your comments and suggestions are welcome!

Comment: In order to profile your spark-scala application, you need to create a cluster (ex: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/stackdriver-logging) which will enable the job driver logs in the Stackdriver Logging when you initialize the gcloud spark-submit command.

Comment: @StefanNeacsu - Thank you for your reply. We are creating a cluster with multiple executors (let's assume 4 for example sake). But how will stack driver logging help us to profile? Would those logs be able to point me towards where is my code spending maximum amount of time?

Comment: For this specific case scenario you should look for Logging and Monitoring (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/stackdriver-monitoring) and by setting some custom metrics I think you can achieve this. I actually did not test for spending maximum amount of time but you have a lot of metrics for your clusters to see if issues arise.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have contacted google (through our company, as we have a support contract). If something comes up - I will be sure to update. :)

Comment: I noticed that you ask the same question on [StackExchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/1002153/profiling-gcloud-spark-submit-with-stackdriver). Did the provided answer help you at all?

Comment: @StefanNeacsu: Google currently doesn't provide profiling for spark applications. But I got to know via our Google contact that the feature is going to be rolled out within a month. We will be using it straight away as we are getting our project white listed. Let's see how it goes and I shall come back on this again.

Comment: @sllopis: Well I am aware of the facts given in the answer and I have also tried the suggestions & options mentioned in there. But I have hit roadblocks on at least 2 options. For sparklens - I have an open ticket (https://github.com/qubole/sparklens/issues/50) and same goes for flamegraph, I also have an open ticket (https://github.com/spektom/spark-flamegraph). I shall update If I make any progress on the said issues.

Comment: @sllopis: Out of curiosity - How did you manage to get a hyperlink in there? I didn't get that option. :). Or is it that I have missed something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that this same question was answered in this other [StackExchange post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1002153/profiling-gcloud-spark-submit-with-stackdriver), in which there is an accepted answer. Also, I'm aware that you are waiting on some Spark-related issues to be resolved. Do you have any additional questions in regards to the question stated above in this thread?

Comment: As for the embedded hyperlinks, you need to follow the `[title_of_your_link](url)` format.

Comment: As of now I am not waiting for any answers in this post.